# how do you restart a while loop halve way through?

Tags: javascript

is there a way I can restart a while loop halve way through it with out changing its condition?

```
while(health > 0 &&enemyhealth > 0){
    if(attack)
    {
        attack
    }

    if(view stats)
    {
       console.log(stats)
       restart loop
    }

    enemy attack
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you want `continue`.

```
while (health > 0 && enemyhealth > 0){
   ...

    if (...)
    {
       ...
       continue; // This will skip the rest of the loop body,
                 // check the loop condition again, and keep going
                 // if the while condition is still true
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `continue`

```
while(health > 0 && enemyhealth > 0){
    if(attack)
    {
        attack
    }

    if(view stats)
    {
       console.log(stats)
       continue;
    }

    enemy attack
}
```